# jOOQ - support for UPDATE ... SET ... query with arbitrary degree

Tags: sql, sql-update, jooq

I have two functions: one returns a list of fields, the other returns a select query (which selects the corresponding values of the fields).

```
private List<Field<?>> fields() {
    ....
}

private Select<?> select() {
    ...
}
```

Note that the degree is determined at runtime, it depends on the user input. Hence `List<Field<?>>` and `Select<?>`.

It is possible to insert into a table:

```
context.insertInto(table, fields()).select(select()))
```

It is not possible to update a table:

```
context.update(table).set(DSL.row(fields()), select())
```

Could this functionality be added to jOOQ 3.7?

Which workaround can we use for now?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32251307/521799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch, there's a missing method on the [`UpdateSetFirstStep`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetFirstStep.html) DSL API, which accepts [`RowN`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RowN.html) as a first argument, the type returned from [`DSL.row(Collection)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-java.util.Collection-). This should be fixed for jOOQ 3.7:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4475

As a workaround, and if you can live with the guilt of the hack, you could cast to raw types:

```
context.update(table).set((Row1) DSL.row(fields()), (Select) select())
```

You can cast `DSL.row(fields())` to `Row1`, because the internal implementation type returned by `DSL.row(fields())` implements all `Row[N]` types.

Comment: Guilty hacks make software work! Thanks for information.

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. I expected `update(table).set(row expression, select query)` to be translated into `update table set field_1 = alias.field_1, field_2 = alias.field_2, ... from (select query) as alias`. But it is translated into `update table set (field_1, field_2, ...) = (select query)` which is not valid for PostgreSQL. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: The translation looks interesting. Perhaps we can pull this off for older versions of PostgreSQL. On the other hand, PostgreSQL 9.5 now supports this standard syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html. `UPDATE .. FROM` is supported by jOOQ. If you don't get it to work, feel free to ask another question. I'll be around :)

Comment: I will try it out. The only problem here is that I think I cannot write this in a fluent style (since I have to write `.set(field, value)` for each field). I am starting from  a `List<Field<?>>` and `Select<?>`. That is no big deal though.

Comment: @KevinDeGrote? Why not? You can call `Select.asTable("alias")`, and then dereference individual fields from that table... Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are probably right. It can probably be done with something like `update(table).set((Row1) DSL.row(fields()), (Row1) DSL.row(fields().stream().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList())).from(select().asTable("alias"))`. In the stream, I map the fields to the aliased select-table. I'll try it out and let you know!

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: Ooh, very interesting approach. I hadn't thought about it.

Comment: The mapping wasn't even necessary. This works fine: `context.update(table).set((Row1) DSL.row(fields()), (Row1) select().fieldsRow()).from(select())`. Thanks for your feedback! In jOOQ 3.7, I should remove the `(Row1)` casts.