# Update more than 22 values in Jooq

Tags: java, jooq

What is the best way to update table with more than 22 columns? (set more than 22 values)

Can't use **RowN**:

> no suitable method found for set(RowN,RowN)

I can use **set(Field field, T value)** many times, but it's too long.

Jooq version 3.6.2

Comment: The duplicate is almost the same. In the other question, the `set(RowN, Select<?>)` method was missing. But the workaround is the same. Before jOOQ 3.7, you can unsafe cast both `RowN` types to `(Row1)`. In jOOQ 3.7+, this will be supported via https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4475